# How to handle curl request in loop

Tags: bash, shell, curl, syntax

I have bash scripts that send curl requests in a loop. First iterate works correctly, but second has an error like `curl: (6) Could not resolve host:key1, Error: Process completed with exit code 6.`

My code look like

```
IFS=',' read -ra keys <<< "key1, key2, key3, key4, key5"
for key in "${keys[@]}"
do
  echo "Deleting cache for key: $key"
  response=$(curl -X DELETE \
                  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                  -H "Authorization: Bearer GITHUB_TOKEN"\
                  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
                  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPOSITORY/actions/caches?key=$key)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error occurred while deleting key $key"
    continue
  fi
  echo "Response for key $key: $response"
done
```

How can I solve this issue

Comment: `if [ $? -ne 0]` should be `if [ $? -ne 0 ]`. If this throws error, loop will fail

Comment: You can add `set -x` at the very beginning, and once you run it, it will show you a debug of each bash step... so you can examine what the issue is.

Comment: Do you feed the array by hand or it comes from another command?

Comment: @GillesQuénot It comes from another command.

Comment: Can you show which one and which output to allow us to gives best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you declare the array is wrong, check:

```
IFS=',' read -ra keys <<< "key1, key2, key3, key4, key5"
echo "[${keys[1]}]"
[ key2]
```

You have leading unwanted space in your keys. So:

```
IFS=',' read -ra keys <<< "key1, key2, key3, key4, key5"
for key in "${keys[@]}"; do
  key="${key// /}"
  echo "Deleting cache for key: "
  response=$(curl -X DELETE \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer GITHUB_TOKEN"\
    -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPOSITORY/actions/caches?key=$key)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error occurred while deleting key $key"
    continue
  fi
  echo "Response for key $key: $response"
done
```

Here, `key="${key// /}"` trim spaces, using shell simple *parameter expansion*

See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and
`LESS='+/Parameter Expansion' man bash`
Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 0):

Your list/array is introducing a space in front of each KEY.... try cleaning up spaces (see comment in code):

```
IFS=',' read -ra keys <<< "key1, key2, key3, key4, key5"
for key in "${keys[@]}"
do
  key="${key// /}"
  echo "Deleting cache for key: $key"
  response=$(curl -X DELETE \
                  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                  -H "Authorization: Bearer GITHUB_TOKEN"\
                  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
                  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPOSITORY/actions/caches?key=$key)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error occurred while deleting key $key"
    continue
  fi
  echo "Response for key $key: $response"
done
```

Comment: No need to spawn a subshell // using pipes // xargs